# I want to use c# ITEXTSHARP 5.5.13.2 to generate a two-layer PDF file, how do I generate it?

Tags: c#, itext

I used the below representative to generate a problem, where
`cb.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_TOP, "A",0,0, 0);`

The generated text is in the lower left corner of the image,

The function I want to achieve is to open a picture and add it to the page, and then add the specified characters in the specified position. I wonder who can help me?

```
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
string put = "0035.pdf";
PdfWriter PDFwriter=iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(put, 
FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite));        
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.Image image;
image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("0035.jpg");
document.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(image.Width, image.Height));
image.ScaleAbsolute(image.Width, image.Height);
image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
document.NewPage();
document.Add(image);  
PdfContentByte cb = PDFwriter.DirectContent;
cb.SetTextRenderingMode( PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_INVISIBLE);   
BaseFont BFont_TimesRoman = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"c:/windows/fonts/SIMLI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.BeginText();
cb.SetFontAndSize(BFont_TimesRoman, 18);
cb.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_TOP, "A",0,0, 0);
cb.EndText();   
document.Dispose();
```

Comment: Don't post code as images, please. If you need to update it, update the text by editing the post.

Comment: This doesn't look like it is C. C# maybe?